# Sanity check on spider web calculation

Tags: lie-algebras

For fun I began reading an interesting online paper I found, [*Spiders for rank 2 Lie algebras*](http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9712003), and on page $5$ we have the following calculation, akin to a tensor product expansion via bilinearity:

$\hskip 0.8in$ [image: 21]

However, I believe the $21=6+6+9$ should just be a $12=6+6$, so that $9$ appears only once in the final result as the coefficient of the second web you see. What's going on?

(Also, help on more pertinent tags would be appreciated.)

Comment: Do you propose a 'spider' tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. I think the fact that $21=6+6+9$ is a coincidence; I think it is more likely that Prof. Kuperberg transposed the digits $1$ and $2$.